# sqldeveloper excludes a selected date

Tags: oracle, plsql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/843de/2

I try the following code on sqlfiddle, works perfect.

but if i execute one of the following select statements on sqldeveloper...

```
select * from teldat where datum between to_date('04.08.2011','dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date('30.11.2011','dd.mm.yyyy');

select * from teldat where datum <= to_date('30.11.2011','dd.mm.yyyy');
```

...the 30.11.2011 is not included.

I don't know what's wrong. Can anybody give me a hint?

Kind Regards

Comment: From top of my head, try `to_date('30.11.2011 23:59:59','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')` instead. It will default to 00:00:00 otherwise and your rows will be ommited. Not sure how/why it works on sqlfiddle. You could also just try `< to_date('1.12.2011','DD.MM.YYYY')` which will include everything up to 00:00 of 1.12.2011.

Comment: @tvm he could also use trunc(datum) if the dates are all that matters

Comment: You are right, now when I see it, that's the usual way how to do this.

Comment: can you concretize the trunc statement for my example?

Comment: this is not real question, there is nothing wrong, even the date in field datum does not contain hours or minutes, as seen in insert statements http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/843de/2 .

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from teldat where datum <= to_date('30.11.2011 23:59:59','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

this works for me.